# How to update child table while updating master table

Tags: oracle11g

I have a parent table `EMPLOYEE` with columns `(SYSID,SERVICENO,DEPENDENTS...)` (`SYSID` is Primary key) and Child table `EMPLOYEE_ADDRESS (EMPLOYEE_SYSID,CITY,STATE...)` (`EMPLOYEE_SYSID` is foreign key).

Here is my question: when I am updating SYSID in master, how to update the `EMPLOYEE_SYSID` in child table. One more thing: I have 10 more child tables for `EMPLOYEE` table, please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is called an "update cascade", and is best avoided in general by choosing primary keys whose values will not change over time.

If this is a one-off fix, you can temporarily disable the foreign key constraints (while no users are in the database), update all the tables, and then re-enable the constraints.

Tom Kyte has published an update cascade solution [on his blog](http://tkyte.blogspot.co.uk/2009/10/httpasktomoraclecomtkyteupdatecascade.html) if you need an ongoing method.